# How to force Thunderbird to automatically use the email address of received emails in my responding emails

Tags: email

I use numerous email addresses. When I receive emails to any of these I expect my email client, here TB, to understand that should I respond to an email it should automatically use the email address that received the email.

Comment: If you stay in the account to which the mail was sent, on reply, it will come from that same account. If you click on a different account, than that becomes the sender.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  I have about a dozen accounts.  The only time it gets confused is if I move the email to a folder in a different account.

I have switched over to [BetterBird](https://www.betterbird.eu/) recently.  It seems to work better and they have fixed a few bugs too.  And it uses the same engine and database/file collection.

There is a setting to make the link better.  But you have to set it in each email account.  I havent had to use it.  **Reply from this identity when delivery headers match**

[image]